# How to understand the "smallest index" in a WebAssembly function body?

Tags: webassembly

[image]

How to understand the sentence which I distinguish with a red rectangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locals and function parameters are accessed through the same [index space](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/modules.html#indices). An index space is an abstract entity - the implementer is free to place the parameters and locals as they see fit, but the parameters and locals should be accessed through the same index.

This `add2` function which take the parameters $px and $py will access $px at index 0 and $py at index 1:

```
(func $add2 (param $px i32) (param $py i32) 
 get_local 0
 get_local 1
 i32.add)
```

This `add_local` function which only contains one parameter will have $px at index 0 and the local $z at index 1.

```
   (func $add_local (param $px i32) (local $z i32)
     get_local 0
     get_local 1
     i32.add)
```

So the index space for a function consists of

- [0] = param0
- [1 ] = param1
- ...
- [N] = paramN
- [N+1] = local0
- [N+2] = local1
- ...
- [N+M] = localM